# appending <script> to <body> allows me to circumvent the 'same-origin policy'. Or this is not really cross-site-scripting?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, xss

Since my other question ([Why is the 'src' attribute allowed to link to scripts from external domains, and XmlHtppRequests not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27519546/343475)) didn't gave me any answers. I go on the more practical way:

When using jQuery ajax call you are not allowed (by the browser) to do Cross-Site-Scripting, but you can circumvent this by appending a script tag do the DOM.

*some_script.js*

```
$('div').text('The code to show this text was loaded from a different server, this remote script, instructed to update all the div\'s');
```

*cross-site-scripting_example_ajax.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head></head>
<body>
<span>ajax call</span>
<div></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var source =    "http://malicious.s3.amazonaws.com/some_script.js"
        $.get( source, function( data ) {
            eval(data)
            });             
});
    </script>
</body>
```

This will, as expected, not work. It will give in Chrome a **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.** error. Chrome and most other browsers are protecting the user from the danger of Cross-Site-Scripting (XSS).

But when I do the following:

*cross-site-scripting_example_appendto.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head></head>
<body>
    <span>with jQuery appendTo</span>
    <div></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var source =    "http://malicious.s3.amazonaws.com/some_script.js"
        $('<script id="script" src='+source+' >').appendTo('body');
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

It works. The malicuious *"some_script.js"* scripts get executed once it get attached to *body*, since you will see the DOM being updated.

Since this method is quite simple, I don't think I have found a vulnerability, but merely that I don't grasp the cross-site-scripting / same-origin-policy concepts.

Why is the second way (*cross-site-scripting_example_appendto.html*) not cross-site-scripting?

**Rephrase my question**
What can I do with cross-site-scripting (if it would be allowed), that I can't do with appending a new  to ?

Comment: Only 5 sec after posting the question, I at least understand why it works, because the second part uses a HttpRequest, not a XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: I think this link may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25499163/1140531

Comment: script tags aren't restricted to same domain policy

Answer (score 0):

You're a little confused by what cross site scripting involves. Cross-site scripting is when a `user a` inputs some malicious code into your website. `user b` considers themselves on a trusted site, and somehow the input from `user a` reaches `user b`. Thus, the script has "crossed the site".

Comment: I think that is more the area of 'Injection'.

Comment: What do you think a cross site script attack *is*, exactly? It's when one user injects a script into another users browser via your website. I mean, if you took 10 seconds to google it the wikipedia summary says it word for word. Your question is answered: yes, `user a` bypassing same-origin policy by injecting script tags into your site and it affecting `user b` is a cross site scripting attack.

Comment: You as a site owner aren't performing a cross site scripting attack by doing this, because a cross-site scripting attack, specifically, is a "user" of the site targeting other users.